# Android Studio 2.2 cmake error (c++)

Tags: android, cmake, android-studio-2.2

Has anybody tried to use CMake in the new Android Studio 2.2 preview 3?

I'm getting this error on a simple "Hello world" project with C++ support:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing '/home/cobalt/Android/Sdk/cmake/bin/cmake' with arguments {-H/home/cobalt/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloOpenCV/app -B/home/cobalt/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloOpenCV/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/json/mips64 -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=mips64 -DANDROID_NDK=/home/cobalt/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/home/cobalt/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloOpenCV/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/mips64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/home/cobalt/Android/Sdk/cmake/bin/ninja -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/cobalt/Android/Sdk/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=android-23 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-frtti -fexceptions}
```

Comment: Apparently, Android Studio 2.2 CMake is supported only in a 64-bit machine... but I'm still hoping that somebody has a hack for a 32-bit running Android Studio.

Comment: That's way I couldn't find "CMake" among Tools > Android > SDK Manager > SDK Tools... why they don't write this ndk requirement somewhere in android documentation? since downloading all the packages and plugins and tools and updates requires a lot of time :(